# PHP - Run Two Mysql Queries That Use "SELECT" Through a Drop-down Menu

Tags: php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu

Basically, I have a drop-down menu that has two options - 'All' & 'Top Rated'.

```
<select class="dropdown">
<option value="all">All</option>
<option> value="toprated">Top Rated</option>
</select>
```

I want to run this query through the 'All' option...

```
$myQuery  = "SELECT Attraction.*, Type.TypeName, Rating.RatingUrl ";
$myQuery .= "FROM Attraction ";
$myQuery .= "INNER JOIN Type ON Attraction.Type = Type.TypeID ";
$myQuery .= "INNER JOIN Rating ON Attraction.AttractionID = Rating.AttractionID ";
$myQuery .= "WHERE Attraction.Type = 4 ";
$myQuery .= "ORDER BY Name ";

$result = mysql_query($myQuery);
if (!$result) {
    die('Query error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

And the this query through the 'Top Rated' option...

```
$myQuery  = "SELECT Attraction.*, Type.TypeName, Rating.RatingUrl ";
$myQuery .= "FROM Attraction ";
$myQuery .= "INNER JOIN Type ON Attraction.Type = Type.TypeID ";
$myQuery .= "INNER JOIN Rating ON Attraction.AttractionID = Rating.AttractionID ";
$myQuery .= "ORDER BY Rating DESC, Name ";

$result = mysql_query($myQuery);
if (!$result) {
    die('Query error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Can anyone generate the php structure I would need for this to work...

If anyone can help that would be great!

Comment: Hi Peter.  SO isn't a code writing service. Give it a try, and if you get stuck come back and ask for help on *specific* roadblocks you run into.  Happy coding!

Comment: Ohhh, I have tried if statements but i've only just started learning code so don't know how I would structure the code. I know what I think I should write but just don't know how to write it in php :/...

Comment: I'd suggest running through some PHP tutorials.  You'll get the hang of it in no time.

Comment: thanks, any tutorial suggestions? I've had a look on youtube and all over this site but can not find anything that matches what i need to do specifically...

Comment: Seeing as you have no LIMIT constraints these will both return the same entire recordset, just in different orders. "All" vs "Top Rated" seems to imply complete recordset vs a limited subset of the highest rated results. Also to have valid html you need to fix the > before value= in <option> value="toprated">

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this [tutorial for PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp) and this [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) reading

Also, check what WebChemist said:

Not ok:

```
<option> value="toprated">Top Rated</option>
```

Ok:

```
<option value="toprated">Top Rated</option>
```